How do I make pixel animations with Grease Pencil?
I am attempting to make a pixel animation in Blender (not voxel). I have attempted to use the square brush, but for some strange reason, it spaces out the squares. I don't intend to use the Grease Pencil effect Pixelate, for I want to have direct control over everything. I think that the square brush with spacing and no rotation would work fine, but I've encountered this problem:
If anyone knows how to fix this problem, or has a better solution for making pixel art, I would really appreciate it!  

Could you include a screenshot of your workspace?

@Starry-EyedDonut Yeah Sure! It's simply (as of right now) the 2D animation workspace.

Sorry, I meant could you include a photo of the complete workspace, not just the render. :)

@Starry-EyedDonut Added workspace!

Are you using Solid Stroke or Square Stroke? Because it looks like you're using the Solid brush in your workspace.

@Starry-EyedDonut Oh, I never realized that there was a Square stroke by default. I modified the Solid stroke to be a Square stroke. But even when I use the Square Stroke, it still spaces the squares out, as shown in the render.

Okay, so you're using the Solid stroke, but modified to be a Square stroke? (sorry, I'm a little confused.) Which one did you use in the render?

@Starry-EyedDonut The solid stroke I modified. If you didn't notice, the workspace picture shows my settings for the Solid stroke on the right. It also shows that I set the rotation of the squares to fixed, because in pixel art, the squares are never rotated.

I tried modifying the brush on my end and it does the same thing. Let me play around with it a little and see if I can find a solution. :) (however, I'm still very much a newb so I can't promise anything) My only other suggestion would be toying with the settings or downloading the Grease Pencil brush pack from the Blender site and testing some of its brushes. It may have the effect you're going for. :)

I haven't been able to find a solution, as the Square stroke seems intended to space out the strokes. However, I did find this video. I don't know if it's the effect you're going for but I hope it helps you somehow. You might also try searching YouTube for "Pixel art in Grease Pencil". :) https://youtu.be/zdkIyL04_oQ
